# Loosing hash (#) in Angular URL using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

my singlepage angularjs application can be accessed through the root address of my webserver like.
`localhost:8080/`
When I chose to go for example to the home-state the application is supposed change the url in the browsers addessfield to `localhost:8080/#/home` where the first part (`localhost:8080/`) points to my angular application and the second part (`#/home`) points to the home-states url.

But instead of doing what it's supposed to do my angular-application changes the url in the browsers addressfield to `localhost:8080/home` which on reload obviously creates a 404.

Can any of you tell me what I am doing wrong or at least give me a hint on where to look?

Comment: are you sure you aren't using `Html5Mode`?  Also, what version of Angular?  Routing had some breaking changes in Angular 1.6...

Comment: actually, this is covered in depth in the FAQ for ui-router:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable the html5 mode from the config. add/change the following line in the config

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

This will add the `#` to your url.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to say you don't use the HTML 5 mode with the [`$locationProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider). In your `config` file:

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);
```

#### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cL4vm6v/)